# Error in Svelte with SCSS when using "@use '@material/typography/index' as typography"

Tags: sass, svelte

I am just starting out with Svelte and SCSS, and I'm running into an issue when trying to include Material Design's typography in my SCSS file. When I add the line **@use '@material/typography/index' as typography;**, I get the following error when I run `npm run prepare`:

`Error: This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using "with".`

Here's my SCSS file:

```
@use 'sass:color';

@use '@material/theme/color-palette';
@use '@material/typography/index' as typography;


// Svelte Colors!
@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
  $primary: #1e5a9d,
  $secondary: #3a7cb5,
  $surface: #f5f5f5,
  $background: #f5f5f5,
  $error: color-palette.$red-900
);

html,
body {
  background-color: theme.$surface;
  color: theme.$on-surface;
}

a {
  color: #1e5a9d;
}
a:visited {
  color: color.scale(#1e5a9d, $lightness: -35%);



html {
  @include typography.typography('body1');
}

h1 {
  @include typography.typography('headline1');
}

h2 {
  @include typography.typography('headline2');
}

h3 {
  @include typography.typography('headline3');
}

h4 {
  @include typography.typography('headline4');
}

h5 {
  @include typography.typography('headline5');
}

h6 {
  @include typography.typography('headline6');
}

caption {
  @include typography.typography('caption');
}

code,
pre {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

small {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

big {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I fix this and use the Material Design typography in my Svelte app with SCSS?

Comment: share a stackblit to be able to test it but i thisk the reason is that `@use '@material/typography/index' as typography;` cant be in the same file of theme/index because typography also uses themes and you can't `@use` a module twice
put typography in your main svelte style.scss file insted of the theme file